# python flow control functioning weird

Tags: python, list, for-loop, interpreter

I was trying to solve a knapsack problem using DP. Basically, the goal is to see if we can have certain elements in the list sum up to half of the total sum.

```
def canPartition(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: bool
    """
    run_sum = 0
    for num in nums:
        run_sum += num

    if run_sum & 1 == 1:
        return False
    run_sum //= 2

    n = len(nums)
    dp = [[False] * (run_sum+1)] * (n+1)

    for i in range(n+1):
        dp[i][0] = True

    for j in range(1, run_sum+1):
        dp[0][j] = False
    print("initial stage")
    print(dp)

    for i in range(1, 2):
        for j in range(1, run_sum+1):
            dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j]
            print("inner loop after operation 1:")
            print(dp)
            if j >= nums[i-1]:
                print("inner loop after operation 2:")
                print(i, j)
                dp[i][j] |= dp[i-1][(j - nums[i-1])]
                print(dp)
                print(" ")

    return dp[n][run_sum]

nums = [1, 2, 5]
canPartition(nums)
```

The goal itself is not so important here. But the flow control of the last nested loop behaves really strange. Below is the printed result.

```
initial stage
[[True, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False]]
inner loop after operation 1:
[[True, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False]]
inner loop after operation 2:
1 1
[[True, True, False, False, False], [True, True, False, False, False], [True, True, False, False, False], [True, True, False, False, False]]

inner loop after operation 1:
[[True, True, False, False, False], [True, True, False, False, False], [True, True, False, False, False], [True, True, False, False, False]]
inner loop after operation 2:
1 2
[[True, True, True, False, False], [True, True, True, False, False], [True, True, True, False, False], [True, True, True, False, False]]

inner loop after operation 1:
[[True, True, True, False, False], [True, True, True, False, False], [True, True, True, False, False], [True, True, True, False, False]]
inner loop after operation 2:
1 3
[[True, True, True, True, False], [True, True, True, True, False], [True, True, True, True, False], [True, True, True, True, False]]

inner loop after operation 1:
[[True, True, True, True, False], [True, True, True, True, False], [True, True, True, True, False], [True, True, True, True, False]]
inner loop after operation 2:
1 4
[[True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True]]
```

You can see that, even the value of i was 1 for the entire nested loop, somehow the values of dp[i>1] was modified in the loop. And even j from 1 to 4 was modified as well. It was like there was another "for i in range()" inside the loop. Does anyone have an idea why is this happening? I runned the code with python 3.6.1

Comment: Your list is a copy of single element, you are way more productive if you just use numpy for this. I can smell some matlab background of yours :)

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
dp = [[False] * (run_sum+1)] * (n+1)
```

creates a list of `n + 1` references to the *same* list of `False`s. A simpler example:

```
>>> x = [[False]]*3
>>> x
[[False], [False], [False]]
>>> x[0][0] = True
>>> x
[[True], [True], [True]]
```

You almost never want to use `*` with a list; use a list comprehension instead to get independent lists:

```
dp = [[False for _ in range(run_sum+1)] for _ in range(n+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
 dp = [[False] * (run_sum+1)] * (n+1)
```

the `* (n+1)` doesn't magically create copies of the inner list. Instead it's just making a list of `(n+1)` references to the same list.

Comment: isn't this the same answer ?

Comment: Basically. They were posted more or less simultaneously. It happens.